# zend how to validate 3 separate form in same action?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, zend-framework

So, I have 3 forms on the same page and same controller action, when I click on one of the submit button, it validates all forms instead of the one I clicked.

how can I separate it from validation??

here my code:

```
public function signUpAction()
{
    $firstName = $this->getRequest()->getParam('firstName');
    $lastName = $this->getRequest()->getParam('lastName');
    $email = $this->getRequest()->getParam('email');
    $emailAdrress = $this->getRequest()->getParam('Email_Address');
    $password = $this->getRequest()->getParam('password');

    $signupForm = new Application_Form_UserSignUp();
    $loginForm = new Application_Form_UserLogin();
    $retreivePasswordForm = new Application_Form_UserRetreivePassword();

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost('signupForm'))
    {
        /*********** Sign Up Form ***********/
        if ($signupForm->isValid($this->getRequest()->getParams()))
        {
            $user = $this->_helper->model('Users')->createRow($signupForm->getValues());   
            if ($user->save())
            {
                Zend_Session::rememberMe(186400 * 14);
                Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->write($user);
                $user->sendSignUpEmail();
                $this->getHelper('redirector')->gotoRoute(array(), 'invite');
                return;
            }
            else 
            {
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // something
        }
    }
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost('loginForm'))
    {
        /************ Login Form ************/
        if ($loginForm->isValid($this->getRequest()->getParams()))
        {
            $user = $this->_helper->model('Users')->createRow($loginForm->getValues()); 
            $user = $this->_helper->model('Users')->fetchRowByFields(array('email' => $email, 'hash' => $password));

            if($user) 
            {
                Zend_Session::rememberMe(86400 * 14);
                Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->write($user);
                $this->getHelper('redirector')->gotoRoute(array(), 'invite');
                return;
            } 
            else {
                // Error message
                $this->view->errorMsg = "<b>password</b> - invalid, please try again! *";
            }               
        }
        else
        {
            // something
        }
    }
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost('retreivePasswordForm'))
    {
        /****** Retreive Password Form ******/
        if ($retreivePasswordForm->isValid($this->getRequest()->getParams()))
        {
            $user = $this->_helper->model('Users')->createRow($retreivePasswordForm->getValues()); 
            $user = $this->_helper->model('Users')->fetchRowByFields(array('email' => $emailAdrress));
            if($user)
            {
                Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->write($user);
                $user->sendRetreiveEmail();

                $_SESSION['email'] = $emailAdrress;

                $redirector = $this->_helper->getHelper('redirector');
                $redirector->setCode(301)->setUseAbsoluteUri();
                $newPath = 'http://refer.lavasoft.com/#retreive_sent';
                $redirector->gotoUrl($newPath);

                //$this->view->assign('sendEmail', $emailAddress);
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // something
        }

    }

    $this->view->retreivePasswordForm = $retreivePasswordForm;
    $this->view->loginForm = $loginForm;
    $this->view->signupForm = $signupForm;
}
```

Comment: Erm... why do you think `isPost()` method should take your form name into account? In ZF1, at least, it ignores the params given, instead returning true or false based only on the type of request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how it works in ZF. You cannot pass the form name to isPost() unless you override isPost() in your code.

What you could do is Define all your fields like:

```
loginForm[name]
loginForm[password]
```

and

```
signupForm[name]
```

etc 
then just check for `isset($_POST['loginFom'])`

This should work fine.

Or use a hidden field named formName and check in your code what's its value is.

You can also use a different action for each form and in the end redirect to the signUpAction wich would yeld the same result without the hassle.